# How to run clustered JBoss on two diffrent servers

Tags: jboss

I have two linux servers having JBoss on each server. I need to run clustered JBoss on both server.

I have tried below command for clustering on both servers:

On server one:

```
./run.sh -c all -g DocsPartition  -u 239.255.100.100 \ -b server1'sIP -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1
```

On server two:

```
./run.sh -c all -g DocsPartition  -u 239.255.100.100 \ -b server1's  -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=2
```

So after execute these command it shows message like this:

> 06:11:28,688 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.1 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_5_1_1 date=201105171607)] Started in 40s:289ms

Which indicates that server has started successfully. **So how I can check that JBoss is clustered?**

Comment: Very nice! But what is the problem?

Comment: How can I check that JBoss is clustered now?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for help on formatting a question.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am new here. I'll keep in mind from now.

Answer (score 1):

Please login to `http://<ipaddress>:<port>/jmx-console` and look for the following parameters
`org.jboss.ha.framework.server.ClusterPartitionMBean` contains a method called getCurrentView() which returns list of members forming the cluster. It returns a Vector of Strings representing the host:port values of the nodes

Comment: From where I can get the useraneme/password to get login to
xx.xx.xx.xx/jmx-console

Comment: Actually I am unable to login to "x.x.x.x/jmx-console" using server's credentials.

Comment: Ty with default admin/admin. As far as I know it shouldn't require password, but if it's not working without password, then you might want to verify with administrator who configured JBoss.

Comment: JBoss promotes JOPR for looking at more information about JBoss servers. You might want to give it a try
http://www.jboss.org/rhq

Comment: No this is not working. I have checked for the credentials inside the file "\usr\lib/jboss-eap-5.1\jboss-as\server\default\conf\props" and admin=admin is mentioned there but that is aldo not working.

Comment: Is there any other way to reset the password?